# Why is this query failing?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

When I run this query:

```
SELECT m.tag_id, m.product_id, count(m.product_id) as dups
FROM product_tag_map m
INNER JOIN category_tag_map s ON s.tag_id = m.tag_id
INNER JOIN cart_product p ON m.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE m.product_id = p.product_id
AND s.category_id =508
AND s.include =1
AND dups = (SELECT count(s.category_id) as cats FROM category_tag_map s WHERE s.category_id =508)
GROUP BY m.product_id
ORDER BY dups DESC
```

I get this error:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'dups' in 'where clause'

If I take dups out of the where clause I get this:

```
tag_id  product_id  dups
2   7038    2
2   1294    1
```

I guess I can not use the dups field in the where clause because that field is being generated on the fly. So how can I do what I am trying to do then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are filtering an aggregate you would need to use `Having`. MySQL does actually allow you to reference column aliases in a having clause (most other RDBMS's don't allow this)

```
SELECT m.tag_id, m.product_id, count(m.product_id) as dups
FROM product_tag_map m
INNER JOIN category_tag_map s ON s.tag_id = m.tag_id
INNER JOIN cart_product p ON m.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE m.product_id = p.product_id
AND s.category_id =508
AND s.include =1
GROUP BY m.product_id
HAVING dups = (SELECT count(s.category_id) as cats FROM category_tag_map s WHERE s.category_id =508)
ORDER BY dups DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

**dups** is just an alias for the result of `count()`.. i'm not sure if you can use `count(m.product_id)=(SELECT ...)` in the **WHERE** clause, if it doesn't i'd say that you could test it in the **HAVING** clause